# Splash Screen is show but next screen app crashed logcat error is shown error something like this

Tags: android

```
08-17 06:27:52.494 8079-8079/? E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(SourceFile:739)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze(SourceFile:705)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:328)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:294)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:281)
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(SourceFile:37)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1759)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1734)
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(SourceFile:31)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6420)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6012)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5951)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqp()Ljava/lang/String; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.setting.noshairamjad7.wallpaper-1/base.apk)
      at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzb(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(SourceFile:739) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze(SourceFile:705) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:328) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:294) 
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:281) 
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(SourceFile:37) 
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1759) 
      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1734) 
      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(SourceFile:31) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6420) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6012) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408) 
08-17 06:27:53.881 8079-8079/com.setting.noshairamjad7.wallpaper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.setting.noshairamjad7.wallpaper, PID: 8079
```

here is gradle  it's my first post so sorry if not properlyposted [image]

Comment: Do not post images of code . add it in code format .

Comment: This is not the error but for your sake please Start  using implementation instead of compile.

Comment: @mnp343 it's error is same after implemnet but it's problem in code then

Comment: @mnp343 it's error is same after implemnet but it's problem in code then?

Comment: Yeah that's what I told it's not an error regarding implementation keyword. But a suggestion for keep with latest stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1.You should never include this dependency! It brings in all of the play-services-{x} libraries into your app at once. Just remove this line

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

2. Could you try updating dependencies to a later version? That means change all the 25.3.1 dependencies to 26.0.1 or 27.0.0 and all the 9.0.0 dependencies to 11.4.2 or 11.6.0.

it helps you

Comment: Did you check the gradle pic?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is that use Fireabase Assistant to initialize the Firebase in your application

First remove all firebase dependency and apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' from your app gradle ( in Android Studio 2.3.3) follow this step

```
Tools > Firebase
(On right tab) Assistant > Authentication
```

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqp()Ljava/lang/String; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.setting.noshairamjad7.wallpaper-1/base.apk)
>         at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zzb(Unknown Source)

A missing ProGuard rule ?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/

Comment: i think Progaurd rule is optional

Comment: if it is madetarary can you tell me  how to do it  because i don't know anything about it and i don't know where to add and what to add